# Save pandas merge from within a loop

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm passing chunks of 1,000 rows and merging them within a pandas dataframe but the merged dataframe isn't saved and there's a new datagframe output each time. How can I save the merge each iteration?

```
def mergeDFs:
    def merge(x):
        df = df.merge(x, left_on="id", right_on="id")


    reader = pd.read_csv("train_lag.csv", chunksize=1000)

    for r in reader:
        merged = merge(r)
    return merged
```

Comment: Please, ident correctly yourcode

Comment: @ansev apologies, missed the top line

Comment: where is preprocess function defined? is that a typo?

Comment: use .append to eppend them to an array that is outside the loop

Comment: @abhilb sorry, it was meant to be merge (r), I was copying from phone so misread it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `concat` via a list comprehension:

```
def proc_merge(x):
  return df.merge(x, on="id")

reader = pd.read_csv("train_lag.csv", chunksize=1000)

final_df = pd.concat([proc_merge(r) for r in reader])
```

Comment: This worked, but returning final_df returned more rows than either had originally.

Comment: That might mean your IDs are not unique in either data frame so many-to-many merge is occurring. Any additional field to consider? Try also concatenating first then merging entire `train_lag` dataframe with `df`.

Comment: You were absolutely right, thank you lots. Rearranging the Id field fixed my issue